# What famous dialogue does this Java code represent?

Tags: rebus, computer-puzzle

The following is a text rebus in the form of Java code:

```
public class GetBoolean {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean i = getBoolean();
    }

    private static boolean getBoolean() {
        throw new BOOLEAN();
    }

    private static class BOOLEAN extends RuntimeException {
    }
}
```

It represents part of a famous dialogue.  What dialogue is that?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> I think it's the famous exchange from [A Few Good Men](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Few_Good_Men) where the protagonist demands about the death of a soldier answers at a military tribunal from the guilty base commander
>     `Kaffee: I want the truth!`
>     `Col. Jessup: You can't handle the truth!`
>  after which Colonel Jessup, played by Jack Nicholson, goes on his rant.
>
>  The `getBoolean` method tries to get the truth (Boolean), but is unable to exception-handle it, causing a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Correct, good job!  I originally had `b` as the variable in the main method, but then realized `i` would be more appropriate.  Too bad the main method didn't put the call to getBoolean in a try/catch block, otherwise it could have handled the truth!