# Five Linux command line rebus puzzles

Tags: rebus, computer-puzzle

Solve the following 5 text rebuses, which are in the form of Linux (bash) command lines.

---

**Rebus #1** (solved by [Prem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/18152/4450))

```
# type beep sound > file.txt 2> file2.txt
```

Hints:

> 1. The solution is a single word that appears in dictionary.com.
>  2. The word has 10 letters.

---

**Rebus #2** (solved by [frodoskywalker](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/18108/4450))

```
# cat file.png | wc -w
1000
```

---

**Rebus #3** (solved by [frodoskywalker](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/18108/4450))

```
# touch file1; while true; do mv file1 file2; mv file2 file1; done
```

---

**Rebus #4** (solved by [Geobits](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18105/five-linux-command-line-rebus-puzzles#comment57316_18110)/[karhell](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/18110/4450))

```
# echo -e "\e[0;97m\a"
```

---

**Rebus #5** (solved by [karhell](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/18110/4450))

```
# fsck /dev/sda1 &
```

---

Note: For your answer to be accepted, it must at a minimum contain the correct solution for Rebus #1.

Comment: This is frustrating. I see what the commands _do_, but apart from 2 and (possibly) 5, I have no idea what the rebus is supposed to _mean_

Comment: I can't concentrate on the puzzles because the [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) in #2 is really bothering me. :P

Comment: @Doorknob Haha, true. I guess I really wanted to use a pipe for one of the puzzles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer for #1 :

> stereotype

Explanation :

> stereo == two channels + type , forcing "output" to both STDERR & STDOUT.

Other rebuses have already been answered.

Comment: Good job.  Since Rebus #1 was the most difficult, you get the checkmark.  I wonder how long it would have lasted if I hadn't provided any hints?

Comment: @pacoverflow , your clue about "one word" did help, and the clue about "10 letters" was helpful to select the one word out of many, starting with "stereo". The other answers acted as clues or inspiration. Nice set of rebuses, and I could solve only 1,2&5,

Comment: Oh so you did a search on words containing "stereo"?  I figured someone would do a search on words containing "type".

Comment: @pacoverflow , yes, I went that way because, I initially thought that "type" was used only to generate STDOUT & STDERR so two channels so stereo- (other answers being related to picture&sound&noise), then 10 letters made -type fit.

Comment: Brilliant! I thought "sound" was significant, but would never have thought about stereo. +1 to you (would be more if I could)

Answer (score 16):

Tentative answer :
rebus #1:

> Could it be a sound filter ?

Explanation :

> **type beep sound** tells us what beep and sound are.
>  **> file1.txt** redirects stdout to file1.txt
>  **2> file2.txt** redirects stderr to file2.txt
>  beep is a legitimate command, so type beep is redirected to file1
>  sound on the other hand is not, so it gets redirected to file2

Rebus #2 and #3:
Agreed with @frodoskywalker, see [their answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/18108/13753) for details

> A picture is worth a thousand words, and Perpetual motion

Rebus #4:
(thanks @Geobits)

> White noise

Explanation :

> **echo -e** outputs its arguments taking ansi escapes into account
>  **\e[0;97m** is ansi for bold, high-intensity white
>  **\a** is an ascii bell character
>  A bell makes noise, therefore we have white noise.

Rebus #5:

> To run a background check

Explanation:

> **fsck /dev/sda1** runs a filesystem consistency check on /dev/sda1 (main partition)
>  **&** allows the command to run in the background

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. I thought it was "check yourself" but couldn't see what meaning the ampersand added.

Comment: Maybe "clear as a bell"?

Comment: @Schism No, rebus #4 doesn't have "clear" in it.

Comment: White noise then? A bell *should* make a noise, at least on computers that allow it.

Comment: @Geobits That's right, feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: @pacoverflow I think you preempted that with "*For your answer to be accepted, it must at a minimum contain the correct solution for Rebus #1.*" I could post it, but I'd just as well see it edited into one of the existing answers, since I have no clue at all about #1.

Comment: For Rebus #4, I used 97m instead of 37m because 37m looks gray.

Comment: Ah, right, that makes sense :)

Comment: "sound filter" is not the correct answer for Rebus #1.

Comment: actually, it looks like [type](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_type.htm) returns true, in which case file1.txt accepts true. File2.txt has no error, and so doesn't accept anything, leading to the phrase: "You want the truth?" "you can't handle the truth!"

Comment: @Nyk232 The `type` command doesn't print out "true".  Anyway, did you see [this puzzle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11491/what-famous-dialogue-does-this-java-code-represent) of mine?  I already used those phrases!

Comment: @pacoverflow my bad, didn't see them :( I'll think it over some more...

Answer (score 14):

Rebus #2

> A picture is worth a thousand words

Because

> You have piped an image (file.**png**) to wc and asked it to count the words (-w), which returned 1000

Rebus #3

> Perpetual motion

Because

> You are moving a file forever ('while true')

Answer (score 4):

Possible answer for #1

> Bleep out (beep out)

Explanation

> When you bleep something out the sound goes away, and as karhell was saying the sound isn't a legitimate command

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE.  Sorry but that is not the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible answer for #1:

> soundcheck

because

> The `type` command indicates what would happen if the name (or names) given as argument(s) were to be entered at the command line. `> file.txt` means "write the output of this instruction to a file called "file.txt", and `2> file2.txt` means "write any error messages to a file called "file2.txt". Sound engineers often repeat the numbers "one" and "two" when checking microphone levels; perhaps this is what is being referred to.

Comment: Not a bad guess, although not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Possible answer to #1:

> Tinnitus

Explanation:

> You get a beep, but there's no sound

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE. Sorry but that is not the correct answer.