# The great puzzle

Tags: knowledge, computer-puzzle

Someone one was trying to find out something, according to the following UNIX commands.

```
   $ ssh I@world
Password: 
   [world ~]$ who -H
USER     LINE     WHEN
I        terminal 1865
```

**Who was it? And to what famous quote does it refer to?**

Comment: Should this get the rebus tag, by analogy with [What famous line does this Linux command line represent?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11025/what-famous-line-does-this-linux-command-line-represent) and [What famous dialogue does this Java code represent?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11491/what-famous-dialogue-does-this-java-code-represent)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think it was

> Alice

and the quote is

> Who in the world am I? Ah, *that*'s the great puzzle.

Explanation for those not familiar with SSH:

> `$ ssh I@world` starts an SSH shell and logs in to "world" as user "I" 
>  Next, you type in your password (obviously not visible. I wonder what it is). 
>  `who -H` in the SSH shell gives a list of users currently logged in. The `-H` option tells the program to write column headings (USER, LINE, WHEN)

Explanation for the year:

> Alice in Wonderland was published in 1865

Comment: Ah, a great puzzle indeed.

Comment: *The* great puzzle, even.

Comment: I'm a bit sad you did not state the whole quote ... ;)

Comment: @fffred Well, the code doesn't seem to contain a reference to the second part of the quote...

Comment: @BaSzAt, correct, but it gives the connection to the title