# What movie quote does this represent?

Tags: rebus, knowledge, computer-puzzle

This describes the quote:

```
private function cross(question:Boolean):Number {
    if (question) {
        var answer:Number = Math.sqrt(-1);
    }
    return answer;
}
trace("Answer:", cross(truth));
```

Comment: Don't know which language this is... Does "answer" go out of scope after the if-block?

Comment: @KeyboardWielder I think it's ActionScript. I don't know if it actually compiles though.

Comment: @BaSzAt 'Tis Actionscript. Does compile.

Comment: Same general idea and same answer as [What famous dialogue does this Java code represent?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11491/what-famous-dialogue-does-this-java-code-represent?rq=1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess

> "You can't handle the truth", from *A Few Good Men*. I'm assuming that a complex number can't be handled by whatever Number is.
>
>   **EDIT:** Doing some research, it seems that no, complex number handling is not built in to AS's Number class and as such this is a valid interpretation of the above code.

Comment: The funny thing is that as soon as I saw the function named "cross" (as in cross-examine), this is the quote I thought it would be, but I couldn't figure out how it connected.

Answer (score 4):

My try:

> I am the answer to your prayers.

From the movie:

> [End of days](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0146675/?ref_=nv_sr_1)

Explanation:

> the variable `truth` can mean `true`.  So the `if` statement is evaluated to true and the answer is always $\sqrt{-1}$ which is `i`.
>  'cross' can be a reference to `prayer`. I know it's a long shot but maybe...